# Populating spinner from a List

Tags: java, android

I'm having some difficulties populating a `Spinner` with a `List` type.

Aim: When a `Button` is pressed on the main menu, it executes the task GetTownsTask which populates a `Spinner` on the new screen, but it breaks when setting the `Adapter`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private class GetTownsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... p)  {

        // api calls
        List<String> towns = new ArrayList<String>();
        // populate towns
        return towns;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> townList) {

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                townList.toArray( new String[0] ));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);    // line 124, breaks here
    }
}
```

**Crash Log**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main, 
java.lang.NullPointerException,
at com.project.MainActivity$TestTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:124)
```

**Spinner screen**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#787878">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/townTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/townTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: may be `spinner` is `null`. You add it in your `XML` file?

Comment: `spinner` is null, hard to tell why without any extra code.

Comment: You have towns at top, but you are calling townList.toArray(). Did you check townList is not null by debugging inside onPostExecute method?

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem - I did add it to my xml, otherwise how would the code find it?

@thinksteep - townList is not null within onPostExecute()

Comment: what is line `124` in `MainActivity.java`

Comment: Line 124: spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: then your `spinner` is `null` for sure. Code can find it, If it is add in any of your xml files. make sure xml file use in `setContentView` have `Spinner` with id `spinner`

Comment: Ok, the problem was I had the code in the wrong class, the Task code should have been in the class for the new screen, rather than the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `townList.toArray(new String[0])`. Trying using `townList.toArray()` , this will ensure that the String array created is of the same size as townList.

Comment: `townList.toArray()` had to be casted with String[] which lead to this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                townList.toArray( new String[0] ));
```

It seems that you do not need `.toArray` as you can pass on a `List<String>` object to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.

So try,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                MainActivity.this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
                townList);
```

This assumes that townList is actually being populated in `doInBackground()` and it's return value is being passed on to `onPostExecute(townList)`